# unable to extract textlayoutbuilder-1.0.0.aa while running react-native run-android

Tags: android-studio, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Im getting below error while trying to run react-native run-andriod

can some one help me?

> Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature. :app:preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
>   **:app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library
>   FAILED**
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayou
>     tbuilder100Library'.
>
>   > **Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\abc.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.f
>   >     acebook.fbui.textlayoutbuilder\textlayoutbuilder\1.0.0\fd6e565b07f8a3eed47ada628
>   >     ff17b09545a6ee7\textlayoutbuilder-1.0.0.aar'.**
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

**Stacktrace output**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library'.
> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\409399\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.fbui.textlayoutbuilder\textlayoutbuilder\1.0.0\fd6e565b07f8a3eed47ada628ff17b09545a6ee7\textlayoutbuilder-1.0.0.aar'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not expand ZIP 'C:\Users\409399\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.fbui.textlayoutbuilder\textlayoutbuilder\1.0.0\fd6e565b07f8a3eed47ada628ff17b09545a6ee7\textlayoutbuilder-1.0.0.aar'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.ZipFileTree.visit(ZipFileTree.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree$FilteredFileTreeImpl.visit(AbstractFileTree.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.visit(CompositeFileTree.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:515)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:325)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DelegatingCopySpecInternal.walk(DelegatingCopySpecInternal.java:206)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.process(CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopyAction.execute(FileCopyAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.execute(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.execute(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyActionExecuter.execute(CopyActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopier.doCopy(FileCopier.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopier.copy(FileCopier.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.copy(DefaultFileOperations.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.copy(AbstractProject.java:818)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.copy(AbstractProject.java:814)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LibraryCache.unzipAar(LibraryCache.java:71)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PrepareLibraryTask.prepare(PrepareLibraryTask.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:621)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:604)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: archive is not a ZIP archive
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.positionAtEndOfCentralDirectoryRecord(ZipFile.java:771)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.positionAtCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:707)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.populateFromCentralDirectory(ZipFile.java:452)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:190)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.archive.ZipFileTree.visit(ZipFileTree.java:75)
    ... 100 more
```

Comment: check the location where the studio has been installed.Post your module level gradle file

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's an issue with images in the assets. Try removing the @3x @2x notation, see if it helps!

Comment: what images, what assets? How does this have anything to do with the stacktraces and errors OP posted?

Comment: for me the prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library was caused by faulty translation of the images in js/assets from javascript to android.. don't you have images in your project?